# Encrypted network protocol in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, node.js, stream, protocols

This is just an exercise. I know I should not implement encryption protocol myself. I know I should use Node's TLS package. I know I do not authenticate other side, but merely encrypting traffic.

I have decent experience with NodeJS but not with buffers and streams. And that is where I'd like to here from you. I'd like to hear/read:

- How can I make this more modular, more elegant, more reusable, more flexible. Comments about my class `BufferFiller` are particularly welcomed.
- Any best practices when it comes to using buffers and streams to implement protocols in this asynchronous world? Any design patterns?
- How to improve performance if there is room for that.

Server side:

```
const net = require('net');
crypto = require("crypto");

const algorithm = "aes-256-cbc";
const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const port = process.env.PORT || 6000;

class BufferFiller {
    constructor(inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.lastChunkOffset = -1;
        this.lastChunk = null;
    }

    fill(buffer) {
        let bufferFillLength = 0;
        if (this.lastChunk) {
            const copyLen = Math.min(buffer.length - bufferFillLength, this.lastChunk.length - this.lastChunkOffset);
            this.lastChunk.copy(buffer, bufferFillLength, this.lastChunkOffset, this.lastChunkOffset + copyLen);
            bufferFillLength += copyLen;
            this.lastChunkOffset += copyLen;
        }
        if (this.lastChunk && this.lastChunkOffset === this.lastChunk.length) {
            this.lastChunkOffset = -1;
            this.lastChunk = null;
        }
        if (bufferFillLength === buffer.length) {
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this));
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const onData = chunk => {
                let chunkOffset = 0;
                const copyLen = Math.min(buffer.length - bufferFillLength, chunk.length - chunkOffset);
                chunk.copy(buffer, bufferFillLength, chunkOffset, chunkOffset + copyLen);
                bufferFillLength += copyLen;
                chunkOffset += copyLen;

                if (chunkOffset < chunk.length) {
                    this.lastChunkOffset = chunkOffset;
                    this.lastChunk = chunk;
                }

                if (bufferFillLength === buffer.length) {
                    this.inputStream.removeListener('data', onData);
                    this.inputStream.removeListener('error', onError);
                    resolve(this);
                }
            };
            const onError = err => {
                this.inputStream.removeListener('data', onData);
                this.inputStream.removeListener('error', onError);
                reject(err);
            };
            this.inputStream.on('data', onData);
            this.inputStream.on('error', onError);
        });
    }

    getRemainingBuffer() {
        if (this.lastChunk === null) {
            return Buffer.alloc(0);
        }
        const result = Buffer.alloc(this.lastChunk.length - this.lastChunkOffset);
        this.lastChunk.copy(result, 0, this.lastChunkOffset);
        return result;
    }
};

function exchangeKeysAndPipeThroughDecipher(outputStream, inputStream, nextStream) {
    const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);

    const alice = crypto.createDiffieHellmanGroup('modp14');
    const alicePublicKey = alice.generateKeys();
    const aliceGenerator = alice.getGenerator();
    const alicePrime = alice.getPrime();
    const buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
    buf.writeUInt32BE(aliceGenerator.length, 0);

    outputStream.write(buf);
    outputStream.write(aliceGenerator);
    outputStream.write(alicePrime);
    outputStream.write(alicePublicKey);

    const bobPublicKey = Buffer.alloc(256);

    new BufferFiller(inputStream)
        .fill(bobPublicKey)
        .then(filler => {
            const symKey = alice.computeSecret(bobPublicKey).slice(-32);
            const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, symKey, iv);
            decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
            decipher.write(filler.getRemainingBuffer());
            inputStream.pipe(decipher).pipe(nextStream);
        });
};

async function onClientConnected(sock) {
    exchangeKeysAndPipeThroughDecipher(sock, sock, process.stdout);
};

// Create Server instance
var server = net.createServer(onClientConnected);

server.listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log('server listening on %j', server.address());
});
```

Client side:

```
const net = require('net');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = "aes-256-cbc";
const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const port = process.env.PORT || 6000;
const client = new net.Socket();

class BufferFiller {
    constructor(inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.lastChunkOffset = -1;
        this.lastChunk = null;
    }

    fill(buffer) {
        let bufferFillLength = 0;
        if (this.lastChunk) {
            const copyLen = Math.min(buffer.length - bufferFillLength, this.lastChunk.length - this.lastChunkOffset);
            this.lastChunk.copy(buffer, bufferFillLength, this.lastChunkOffset, this.lastChunkOffset + copyLen);
            bufferFillLength += copyLen;
            this.lastChunkOffset += copyLen;
        }
        if (this.lastChunk && this.lastChunkOffset === this.lastChunk.length) {
            this.lastChunkOffset = -1;
            this.lastChunk = null;
        }
        if (bufferFillLength === buffer.length) {
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve(this));
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const onData = chunk => {
                let chunkOffset = 0;
                const copyLen = Math.min(buffer.length - bufferFillLength, chunk.length - chunkOffset);
                chunk.copy(buffer, bufferFillLength, chunkOffset, chunkOffset + copyLen);
                bufferFillLength += copyLen;
                chunkOffset += copyLen;

                if (chunkOffset < chunk.length) {
                    this.lastChunkOffset = chunkOffset;
                    this.lastChunk = chunk;
                }

                if (bufferFillLength === buffer.length) {
                    this.inputStream.removeListener('data', onData);
                    this.inputStream.removeListener('error', onError);
                    resolve(this);
                }
            };
            const onError = err => {
                this.inputStream.removeListener('data', onData);
                this.inputStream.removeListener('error', onError);
                reject(err);
            };
            this.inputStream.on('data', onData);
            this.inputStream.on('error', onError);
        });
    }

    getRemainingBuffer() {
        if (this.lastChunk === null) {
            return Buffer.alloc(0);
        }
        const result = Buffer.alloc(this.lastChunk.length - this.lastChunkOffset);
        this.lastChunk.copy(result, 0, this.lastChunkOffset);
        return result;
    }
};

client.connect(port, host, function() {
    console.log('Client connected to: ' + host + ':' + port);
    const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);
    const aliceGenLen = Buffer.allocUnsafe(4);
    let aliceGen;
    const alicePrime = Buffer.allocUnsafe(256);
    const alicePublicKey = Buffer.allocUnsafe(256);

    new BufferFiller(client)
        .fill(aliceGenLen)
        .then(filler => {
            const genLen = aliceGenLen.readUInt32BE();
            aliceGen = Buffer.allocUnsafe(genLen);
            return filler.fill(aliceGen);
        })
        .then(filler => filler.fill(alicePrime))
        .then(filler => filler.fill(alicePublicKey))
        .then(filler => {
            const bob = crypto.createDiffieHellman(alicePrime, aliceGen);
            const bobPublicKey = bob.generateKeys();
            client.write(bobPublicKey);
            const symKey = bob.computeSecret(alicePublicKey);
            return symKey.slice(-32);
        })
        .then(symKey => {
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, symKey, iv);
            cipher.setAutoPadding(true);
            process.stdin.pipe(cipher).pipe(client);
        });
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Client closed');
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

I find implementing protocols in asynchronous world particularly difficult, when you can control how much data you receive from underling buffers, nor when ('data' event triggers with what ever chunk size it wants and when ever it wants).

I'm also stuck with Node v8.x, which supports async/await, but I didn't want to hide asynchronicity, on purpose.